# How to group by and retrieve data from mongoDB using MERN stack?

Tags: mongodb, mern

I'm developing a CRM application using MERN stack and I'm storing consultancy information in a collection in mongoDB named "consultinfos". I want to retrieve all the data by grouping using the consultProjestID which is a string. I implemented the backend controller class for this purpose and tested it in postman but there was no output. The controller class and routes I developed for this purpose is given below:

consultController:

```
exports.viewSpecificConsultInfo = async (req,res) => {
      const id = req.query.id;
      try{
          const ConsultInfos = await ConsultInfo.find({consultProjestID: id});
          res.json({ConsultInfos});
      }catch(err){
          console.log(err, 'consultcontroller.viewSpecificConsultInfo error');
          res.status(500).json({
              errorMessage: 'please try again later'
          })
      }
  };
```

routes:

```
router.get('/:id/consultInfo/:id', consultController.viewSpecificConsultInfo);
```

Comment: is collection name is correct?consultinfos vs ConsultInfo also is consultProjestID stored as string vs integer? in mongo DB string and integers are considered different.

Comment: Try logging the `id` value to make sure it looks like you expect.